# Re-direct output text from .exe, till the exe is closed using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to open an exe(exe is capable is taking input) and redirect all the out-put text from .exe till I close the exe

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_f:
    p = subprocess.Popen(r"xx.exe",
                         stdout=output_f,
                         stderr=output_f)
```

If I run the above program , exe is launched immedaitely and gets closed but the text is copied in the output file.

I don't want exe to be closed, exe should be open and when I provide some inputs, exe will provide some text. I want python to keep copying all the text from the exe, till I close the file.

Comment: This depends a lot on how `xx.exe` behaves. Can you describe how it operates?

Comment: xx.exe takes user input pass it to a device and prints the result in exe screen and again provide user option to enter the input.